# Printing a document on macos

Tags: macos, printing, cups

Is there any "print" or "printto" equivalent command under macos ? Simply i wanna send a file to printer but its own content have to be interpreted by default program. So "lpr" or "lp" doesn't help because it's directly sending a file itself to printer. Assume that i have a office document or keynote file that i wanna print it. If i print that file in office or keynote there is no problem but if i use "lpr" or "lp" document's binary content will be written that i don't want.

PS! Sorry for my English...

Answer (score 0):

you should search for "print apple event" when looking up the internet about your problem.

As far as I understand you have to open the document in default application and send this application this event. This can be done with apple script or osascript in bash.

regards,

Robert